# Ajax change button on PHP website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, request

I try to change without refresh status of my button on my PHP page.
I m new in JavaScript code and I see that solutions to my problem uses an AJAX request.

So I did this:

```
function accendi(str) {

  //controllo se id è vuoto
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
    //altrimenti invio la richiesta
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log(xmlhttp);
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    //manda la stringa alla pagina accendi.php
    xmlhttp.open("GET","accendi.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}

function spegni(str) {

  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log(xmlhttp);
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","spegni.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}

<div class="container">

  <section>
    <header>
      <h2 align="center"> Gestione luci </h2>
      <br>
      <br>

 <?php

$fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.100",23);
if (!$fp) {
  echo("<script>alert('Dispositivo non collegato')</script>");
  echo("<script>window.location = 'home.php';</script>");
}
else {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $numrows; $x++) {

    $resrow = mysqli_fetch_row($rest);
    $id= $resrow[0];
    $userT= $resrow[1];
    $statusT = $resrow[2];
  }

if($statusT==0){

  echo "<form method=\"post\" onSubmit=\"accendi($id)\"><p align=center>
  <br> Stato luci : Spente &nbsp;<img src=\"images/rosso.jpg\">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type=\"submit\" name=\"invio\" value=\"Accendi\">
  </p></form>";
}
else if($statusT==1){

  echo " <form method=\"post\" onSubmit=\"spegni($id)\"><p align=center><br>Stato luci : Accese &nbsp;<img src=\"images/verde.jpeg\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"submit\" name=\"invio\" value=\"Spegni\">
  </p></form>";
}
```

And this (one for function), in two different PHP page:

```
require_once('connection.php');

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql= "UPDATE luciajax SET stato=1 where id='".$q."'";

if ($connection->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $connection ->connect_error);
}

//se connessione funziona accendo arduino

if ($connection ->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.100",23);

  fputs($fp,"1");

  fclose($fp);

}

else {
 echo "Error updating record: " . $connection ->error;
}

$connection ->close();
```

But my button often don't work well. Sometimes status do not change, but the database and other PHP code are working fine.

Comment: Are you loading the button via AJAX?

Comment: Your Javascript isn't within `<script>` and `</script>` tags ?!? You probably have some errors in [**console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: no @JayBlanchard

Comment: yes i have a script tag but no error in console @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0):

You defined an `onsubmit` inline handler to your `form`... Which is correct.

But the "normal behavior" of a form submiting is to submit to the ressource provided in the `action` attribute. When it's missing, the form submit to "self".

You obviously don't want this "normal behavior" to occur... Since you defined some ajax functions to replace it.

So you have to "prevent" it, using [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Add this within the `<script></script>` tags:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: yes i had insert   action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\"  because i read that "missing action" isnt correct.
But i try you solution using 

var numInput = document.querySelector("form")
if(numInput){
 numInput.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
}

but my page dindt refresh, and button stay off(or on) , if i manual refresh status change. Thanks for your answear , i hope to find a solution, this make me crazy.

Comment: The thing that makes me angry is that this bug is not specific, but it only happens a few times, for the rest it works well, I update the DB, and also the other functions I run but the state sometimes refreshes no more

Comment: I don't know why you use a condition here... But try `if(numInput.length>0){`. --- Now, you page won't refresh. It is using ajax request to send the info to your server ressource. You should see the response.text in `txtHint`. If you want some more change to your page based on ajax result, you have to make it there.